# Python to c return free(): invalid pointer

Tags: python, c, module

I have a Python module that interface a c-library. In one of the methods a pointer to a byte array with specific size is sent as an argument to a method and in the method this pointer is replaced with a pointer to a new larger array and the old array is freed. The problem is that python still tries to free the old data when the routine ends giving

```
free(): invalid pointer
```

The pointer sent in to the method is set up as this

```py
    e.sizedata = 4
    p = (c_ubyte*4)()
    p[0] = 0x80
    p[1] = 0x02
    p[2] = 0x1B
    p[3] = 0x22
    e.pdata = cast(p, POINTER(c_ubyte))
```

Is there a way to handle this without changing the c library?